# How to customize command palette color and keybindings when creating vscode theme

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Creating a VSCode theme for myself. I like the color configuration I have at the moment, but when I open the command palette, it is 'see-through' making it hard to read. How can I configure the palette when designing my theme?

[image: See through command palette]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To change the background of the command palette, modify the `sideBar.background` setting. [More info](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference#_side-bar)

I had the exact same problem as you so I went hunting for it in the docs. At first I thought it was a list colour setting because changing `list.focusBackground` changes the selected item in the command palette.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is exactly what I was looking for! I actually went along the same path as you trying to change the `list.focusBackground` setting.

Comment: for those looking for it: this does change the highlighting in control palette  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {"list.focusBackground": "#ff0000",}

Answer (score 12):

V1.36 added these two colorCustomizations for the command palette/quick open panel:

```
"quickInput.background": "#ff0000",
"quickInput.foreground": "#fff"
```

Thanks to [add color controls to quick open panel PR](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/74041).

---

And those keybindings shown to the right of each command will be themeable in v1.56 (in Insiders already).  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/a3444b121230a97f3ae07304780ea130ea092542

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "keybindingLabelBackground": "#f00",
  "keybindingLabelForeground": "#f00",
  "keybindingLabelBorder": "#f00",
  "keybindingLabelBottomBorder": "#f00",
  "keybindingLabelShadow": "#f00"
}
```

Comment: For those who are wondering, there is another value for quickInput: `"quickInput.list.focusBackground": "#fff"`

Comment: @UnderBlue592 Should be `"quickInputList.focusBackground"` small typo