# Change VS Code Command Palette highlight color

Tags: colors, visual-studio-code, editor, settings

I only recently made the switch to VS Code and found nice theme.
I am unhappy with the selection of the active elements though. 
In the explorer as well as in the command palette. They are very hard to distinguish from inactive ones.

I found this thread:
[How to customize command palette color when creating vscode theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50883705/how-to-customize-command-palette-color-when-creating-vscode-theme)
But everything in there does not work for me.

Is this answer wrong, or did something change?

I would be very glad if somebody told me how to change this.
Cheers and thanks in advance

-> Example how hard it is to see the active element:

[image]

Comment: `"list.focusBackground": "#ff0000",` works for me to change the selected item in the command palette.

Comment: Hm weird. I tried that before and it is still not working.
Maybe the theme somehow overrides this? I am using `"workbench.colorTheme": "Ayu Mirage",`

Comment: @Mark  `"workbench.colorCustomizations": {"list.focusBackground": "#ff0000",}` works! Please write it in an answer, we ll upvote it.

Comment: @Mark Yes it its, but just writing a answer that link to the original answer would be help the user (like me) to quickly find it, instead of having to read the comments.

Comment: Aah alright. If you use `"workbench.colorCustomizations": {"list.focusBackground": "#ff0000",}` it works. but `"list.focusBackground": "#ff0000",` alone did not... 
thanks @JinSnow

Comment: Sorry, assumed you knew where to put that in your settings.  I'm going to mark this as a duplicate.